# Cache plugin not caching

Tags: caching, grails, groovy

Could some wise guru give me a hand to get the Cache Plugin to work? I have been given this project that uses:

- Grails 3.3.0
- gradle 3.0
- GORM 6.1.6.Release
- Cache Plugin 4.0.0

I'm following https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/snapshot/guide/index.html#usage to enable Caching though the app can be started without error, the method that is annotated by @Cacheable doesn't seem to be caching. This is what my myWebApp**build.gradle** looks like:

```
:
compile group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'cache', version: '4.0.0'
compile group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'async'
:
```

This is my grails-app/conf/**application.yml**:

```
---
grails:
   cache:
      caches:
         name: 'mycache'
---
```

This is how I enable cache in grails-app/conf/**application.groovy**:

```
:
grails.cache.enabled = true
grails.cache.clearAtStartup = true
:
```

This is my myWebApp/**Application.groovy**:

```
package myWebApp
:

class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
   static void main(String[] args) {
      GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
   }
}
```

This is the method in a controller with @Cachable (grails-app/controllers/data/**mycontroller.groovy**):

```
package data
:
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable
:
@Transactinal
class MyController {
   :
   @Cacheable(value='mycache')
   def getSomeId() {
      return anId
   }
:
}
```

In the same controller, I am calling this method for quick test:

```
:
   def index() {

      def id = getSomeId()
      :
   }
:
```

The problem is getSomeId() didn't seem to be cached. Everytime getSomeId() was called, the body was executed in full length (I set a break point to verify). I just want to use a quick and simple cache mechanism for simple things like this.
What did I do wrong?

---

Thanks for all you folks, the cache finally works in my project. HOWEVER, the import for annotation must come from the plugin: grails.plugin.cache.Cacheable works, but org.springframework.annotation.Cacheable doesn't.

Comment: By default, @Cacheable computes key using method parameters.  I don't actually know if that will work when there are no parameters.  Try adding a 'key' attribute (examples in the documentation you linked) and let us know if that works.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I added a key parameter but it still no goes.
@Cacheable(value="mycache", key="site")

Comment: OK, I just looked through a bit more of my code.  (We stopped using the annotations because of problems like this!)  Try moving your cached method into a service.  It looks like calling a method within the same service or controller actually just calls a proxy method which is not annotated.  So in short: move your method to a service and call it from the controller

Comment: If what @Daniel is saying true, try defining your controller as a `singleton` rather than `prototype` -> see http://docs.grails.org/3.1.0/guide/single.html#controllersAndScopes. Then you might be able to get your methods cached properly.

Comment: The cache finally works. The decisive factor that makes it works is to import the declaration from the cache plugin (grails.plugin.cache.Cachable) not from the framework (org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable). Once the proper import is used, cacheable works in both controller and service.

@injecteer, the project has already got settings for singleton controller